# Reading & Appending Data to XML File using PHP & DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am currently using php 5.5.15

This is the code I use to write a simple xml file called comment.xml using DOM. Now the structure of the file as illustrated below is what I require. What I would appreciate is code sample which will allows me to read all users and comments and out put them say to html. and also code sample to append to the file below.

any help much appreciated.

```
/*** a new dom object ***/ 
$dom = new domDocument; 

/*** make the output tidy ***/ 
$dom->formatOutput = true; 

/*** create the root element ***/ 
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "comments" )); 

/*** create the simple xml element ***/ 
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom ); 

/*** add a user element ***/ 
$sxe->addChild("user", $User_Name); 

/*** add a comment element ***/ 
$sxe->addChild("comment", $Comment); 

$dom->save('comment.xml');
```

The output for the above code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<comments>
<user>Joe Blogs</user>
<comment>This is a comment</comment>
</comments>
```

Comment: We have example code for this and similar things already in existing Q&A. It's normally not accepted to ask for code examples as well, but you can exploit the exemplary matter of existing content by searching for it. Asking needs a concrete programming question which make exactly clear what you're asking about. That works best with a condensed, self-containing example that illustrates a concrete programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would suffice

```
$xmlStr = '<container><comments><user>Joe Blogs</user><comment>This is a comment</comment></comments><comments><user>John Doe</user><comment>This is another comment</comment></comments></container>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xmlStr);
if (!$dom) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}

$xmlObj = simplexml_import_dom($dom);


foreach($xmlObj->comments as $child) {
  echo 'user: '.$child->user.'<br>';
  echo 'comment: '.$child->comment.'<br>';
  echo '-----------------<br>';
}
```